# when is $3^{k} \equiv 3^{6l} \pmod {17}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> when is $3^{k} \equiv 3^{6l} \pmod {17}$?

I've understood that the answer is **iff** $k\equiv 6l \pmod {16}$.

Is the reasoning as follows?

Let's assume $k>6l$. Then, $3^{k-6l} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$

So by Fermat's theorem $k-6l \equiv 16\equiv 0\pmod{16}$

and the result follows.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not correct. You need to know that the order of $3$ mod $17$ is $16$.

The same argument would not work for $2^n \equiv 2^0 \bmod 17$. You only get $n \equiv 0 \bmod 8$, since the order of $2$ mod $17$ is $8$.

More drastically, it does not work for $(-1)^n \equiv (-1)^0 \bmod 17$. You only get $n \equiv 0 \bmod 2$, since the order of $-1$ mod $17$ is $2$.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you lhf!